# Are ultralimits the Gromov-Hausdorff limits of a subsequence?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, ultrafilters

Let $(M_i,p_i)$ be a sequence of $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds with lower Ricci curvature bound $-1$. Fix a non-orincipal ultrafilter and let X be the ultralimit of the sequence. 
Does there exists a $p \in X$ and subsequence of $(M_i,p_i)$ converging to $(X,p)$ in the pointed Gromov-Hausdorff sense?

Comment: Yes it is true and follow directly from the definition. However it is not true that the sequence can be found in the ultrafilter, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111842

Comment: The point $p$ will be just be the limit of the $p_i$. I think it's easier to consider the compact case. The non-compact case then follows by repeatedly passing to subsequences as you increase the radius of the balls.